# Align input elements on HTML document

Tags: html, css

How i could align the `input` elements, or ignore the fact that the `input` elements position is set in function of the length of the `p` elements before them ?

[image]

```css
.netconf>input {
  margin-left: 6em;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="ip" class="netconf">
  <p>IP Address</p>
  <input type="text" name="ipaddress" placeholder="XXX.XXX.XXX" />
</div>
<div id="netmask" class="netconf">
  <p>Netmask</p>
  <input type="text" name="netmask" placeholder="XXX.XXX.XXX" />
</div>
<div id="gateway" class="netconf">
  <p>Gateway</p>
  <input type="text" name="gateway" placeholder="XXX.XXX.XXX">
</div>
<div id="hostname" class="netconf">
  <p>Hostname</p>
  <input type="text" name="hostname" placeholder="Whatever" />
</div>
```

Comment: Try this? change "margin-left: 6em;" to "margin-left: 0em;"

Answer (score 1):

As you're probably already aware, the inputs are offset like that because *IP Address* is a longer text than *Netmask* but both have the same right margin.

You could provide a width for your input labels, fixed or relative, instead of a right margin.

```css
.netconf label {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100px; /* <= maybe use a % */
}
```

```html
<div class="netconf">

  <div id="ip">
    <label for="net-ip">IP Address</label>
    <input id="net-ip" type="text" name="ipaddress" placeholder="XXX.XXX.XXX">
  </div>
  
  <div id="netmask">
    <label for="net-mask">Netmask</label>
    <input id="net-mask" type="text" name="netmask" placeholder="XXX.XXX.XXX">
  </div>
  
  <div id="gateway">
    <label for="net-gateway">Gateway</label>
    <input id="net-gateway" type="text" name="gateway" placeholder="XXX.XXX.XXX">
  </div>
  
  <div id="hostname">
    <label for="net-host">Hostname</label>
    <input id="net-host" type="text" name="hostname" placeholder="Whatever">
  </div>
  
</div>
```

**Note: Switch `<p>` for `<label>`, felt more appropriate for a form. Could simplify HTML a bit more too.*

You could also try placing all the input labels in their own element (column) and all the inputs in another. The downside to this approach is trying to align the labels and inputs horizontally typically requires a little more HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the regular HTML structure for that `form` and `float` as css.

*Extra `div` and `p` are not necessary to my point of view* :)

```css
label {
  float: left;
  width: 8em;/* whatever value and unit you want to use.*/
  clear: left;
  border-right: solid red; /* for demo tosee the red line from screenshot*/
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
}

input {
  float: left;
}
/* extra in case you also want to center that form*/
form {
  display:table;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<form action>
  <label for="ipaddress">IP Address</label>
  <input type="text" name="ipaddress" id="ipaddress" placeholder="XXX.XXX.XXX" />
  <label for="netmask">Netmask</label>
  <input type="text" name="netmask" id="netmask" placeholder="XXX.XXX.XXX" />
  <label for="gateway">Gateway</label>
  <input type="text" name="gateway" id="gateway" placeholder="XXX.XXX.XXX">
  <label for="hostname">Hostname</label>
  <input type="text" name="hostname" id="hostname" placeholder="Whatever" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work. Set your wrapper class to block, then give a min-width to your `<p>` tags. All of your text boxes will be spaced properly after them. You can set the min-width to whatever you want to make them fit properly, and if you're worried about them getting too long, set max-width as well.

```css
.netconf {
  display: block;
}    

p {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="ip" class="netconf">
   <p>IP Address</p>
   <input type="text" name="ipaddress" placeholder="XXX.XXX.XXX" />
</div>
<div id="netmask" class="netconf">
<br>
  <p>Netmask</p>
  <input type="text" name="netmask" placeholder="XXX.XXX.XXX" />
</div>
<div id="gateway" class="netconf">
<br>
  <p>Gateway</p>
  <input type="text" name="gateway" placeholder="XXX.XXX.XXX">
</div>
<div id="hostname" class="netconf">
<br>
  <p>Hostname</p>
  <input type="text" name="hostname" placeholder="Whatever" />
</div>
```

Comment: Use `margin` or `padding` instead of a `<br>` to provide separation between the field rows.

Comment: Sure, that's certainly a valid way to do it too :)

Answer (score 0):

Try giving a fixed length to left p elements, so that the input elements will always be equi distant from p elememts

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following style to achieve it:

```
p, input {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 125px;
}
```

Fiddle:https://fiddle.jshell.net/g94rkx91/1/